# iReport doesn't see the data from JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

When I connect to a Jasper Server via iReport Designer and choose a report from it I can see a report template but when I click preview I can't see the data of report. Besides that when I go to Jasper Server web page and choose the same report I can see the data without any troubles. Could please explain me why it happens and how I can resolve this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the Report in the `Repository Navigator` and then click `Run JasperSever Report`. This will execute the report on the Jasperserver and present you the result.